# Passing on a function from parameter into a nested function

Tags: r, scope, nested

I a nutshell I would like to run the following minimal piece of code:

```
library(plyr)

surround = function(my.df, my.var, my.val, my.method) {
    ddply(my.df, my.var, summarize, value = my.method(as.name(my.val)))
}

my.df = data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:4], times = 25),
                   x = rnorm(100))

surround(my.df, "group", "x", mean)
```

However, this leads to `Error: could not find function "my.method"`. I do realize that this is a scoping issue and I should be using `eval` or `substitute` but I can't figure it out.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/hadley/plyr/issues/3) is know bug in plyr

Comment: That issue is closed since 2012 and referenced from a pull request in 2013 but I guess there's still hope :)

Comment: I believe you should move to dplyr!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a customised function instead of summarise, it would work.

```
surround <- function(my.df, my.var, my.val, my.method) {
  ddply(my.df, my.var, function(x) c(value = my.method(x[[my.val]])))
}

my.df <- data.frame(group=rep(letters[1:4], times=25),
                   x=rnorm(100))

surround(my.df, "group", "x", mean)
```

Comment: I was hoping for ease of use with `transform` and `mutate` as well but this will do!